# PnP People picker - how to clear/reset/filter values in onchange event?

Tags: sharepoint-online, spfx-webparts, people-picker, pnp, reactjs

I could fetch the users in on change event  that is `'selectedItems={this.getPickerItems}'`.
But how would I reset or filter values in the control based on some condition?

I tried to assign [] to items in getPickerItems method,but it doesn't work.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The selectedItems property only return the selected users in the control,it's result will not affect the control.
[image]
How do you want to filter the users?

The control provides same default properties to do a filter.
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]